# Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance - while adding new Component to formArray

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray

I'm using the Reactive Forms Approach. I have a form (parent component called: `DeductionInvoicesComponent`):

```
<form [formGroup]="deductionForm">
      <div formArrayName="items" class="well well-lg">
        <app-deduction-invoice-item
          *ngFor="let item of deductionForm.get('items')?.controls; let i=index"
          [index]="i"
          (removed)="deductionForm.get('items').removeAt($event)">
        </app-deduction-invoice-item>
      </div>
</form>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addItem()">Add an item</button>
```

The TypeScript of the parent is following:

```
export class DeductionInvoicesComponent implements OnInit {

  deductionForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deductionForm = this.fb.group({
      items: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  addItem(){
    let control = <FormArray>this.deductionForm.controls.items;
    control.push(DeductionInvoiceItemComponent.buildItem());
  }
}
```

The form can contains multiple `DeductionInvoiceItemComponents` as a `formArray`.
The child component (a single Item called: `DeductionInvoiceItemComponent`) looks the following:

```
<div class="row" [formGroup]="item">
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label class="center-block">Title</label>
      <select class="form-control" formControlName="title">
        <option value="test">test</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-4">
      <label class="center-block">Invoice Number</label>
  <input class="form-control" formControlName="invoiceNumber">
</div>
<button (click)="removed.emit(index)" type="button" class="close text-danger" aria-label="Close">
  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
```

And the TypeScript of that single component which represents an item of the formArray looks the following:

```
export class DeductionInvoiceItemComponent {

  @Input()
  public index: number;

  @Input()
  public item: FormGroup;

  @Output()
  public removed: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  static buildItem() {
    return new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      invoiceNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      grossAmount: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });
  }
}
```

When I click a button `addItem()` I get the following error message:

> Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance

I create that FormGroup using the static function called `buildItem` as you can see. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your **DeductionInvoiceItemComponent**  you have:

```
@Input()
  public item: FormGroup;
```

But you didn't pass it as Input from the parent component. add it:

```
<app-deduction-invoice-item
          *ngFor="let item of deductionForm.get('items')?.controls; let i=index"
          [index]="i"
          [item]='item' // <-- HERE
          (removed)="deductionForm.get('items').removeAt($event)">
</app-deduction-invoice-item>
```

Comment: Wow, that was the problem! Thanks a lot!